# Netatalk NTFS-3G TRANSFER TO RASPBERRY PI HDD - NOT ENOUGH DISK SPACE

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am trying to transfer files from my Mac via Netatalk to a HDD connected to my Pi. I can connect to the HDD from my mac and read/write, but as soon as I try and copy over anything over a couple of GB, it instantly states 'not enough space', there is 3TB of space. I can copy over smaller files, so I think the connection is okay.

I installed NTFS-3G and the HDD is mounted accordingly.

Any help would be much appreciated!!